# Adding items to a dictionary using a function

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to add items to a dictionary using a function, I'm not getting any error message but when I want to display the dictionary items nothing is shown, I'm always getting "Empty".

```
Function Store_Params()
  Dim aDictionary
  Set aDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim comment
  comment = "FALSE"
  Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set objWorkbook1= objExcel1.Workbooks.Open(Environment("STPFilePath"))
  For Each objsheet1 In objworkbook1.Sheets
    If objsheet1.Name = Environment("TestScriptName") Then
      'LastRow = objsheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + objsheet1.UsedRange.Row
      For irow = 1 To 10
        If InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 2).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 3).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 4).Value, "#") = 0 Then
          comment = "TRUE"
        End If
        If comment = "TRUE" Then
          For j = 5 To 10
            aDictionary.RemoveAll
            aDictionary.Add objExcel1.Cells(irow, j).Value, objExcel1.Cells(irow + 1, j).Value
            irow = irow + 2
          Next
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next
  Set Store_Params = aDictionary
  If aDictionary.Exists("name1") Then
    MsgBox aDictionary.Item("name1")
  Else
    MsgBox("Empty")
  End If
  objExcel1.Quit
  Set objSheet1 = Nothing
  Set objWorkbook1 = Nothing
  Set objExcel1 = Nothing
  Set aDictionary = Nothing
End Function

Call Store_Params()
```

This is my script screenshot:

[image]

Any help please, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Why are you removing all the items each time you add a new item?

Comment: It was a mistake, I updated my question

Comment: Without the `aDictionary.RemoveAll` statement you wouldn't have seen an "Empty" message box. Please don't "fix" the code in your question, otherwise it will become unclear what the answers are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of your code doesn't make any sense.

> ```
> For irow = 1 To 10
>   If InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 2).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 3).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 4).Value, "#") = 0 Then
>     comment = "TRUE"
>   End If
>   If comment = "TRUE" Then
>     For j = 5 To 10
>       aDictionary.RemoveAll
>       aDictionary.Add objExcel1.Cells(irow, j).Value, objExcel1.Cells(irow + 1, j).Value
>       irow = irow + 2
>     Next
>   End If
> Next
> ```

You're checking if there is no `#` in any of the first 4 cells of a row. If no `#` is found, you loop `j` from 5 to 10, and with each iteration remove all entries from the dictionary **and** increment the **row index** (`irow`) by 2. Meaning your statement `aDictionary.Add` will add a keys and values from the following ranges:

```
E1:E2
F3:F4
G5:G6
H7:H8
I9:I10
J11:J12
```

But since you remove all entries with every iteration of the inner loop only the key and value from the last range remain (`J11:J12`). Since those cells are empty, you end up with a dictionary that has just one entry where both key and value are empty strings. In JSON notation it would look like this:

```json
{
  "": ""
}
```

That you always get a message "Empty" from this is only natural, because the dictionary doesn't contain an entry "name1".

Now, assuming that what you actually want is fill the dictionary with all keys and values from the data rows and skip over those rows that contain a `#` in any of the first 4 cells, you'd do something like this:

```
For irow = 1 To 10
  If InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 2).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 3).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 4).Value, "#") = 0 Then
    For j = 5 To 10
      aDictionary(objExcel1.Cells(irow, j).Value) = objExcel1.Cells(irow + 1, j).Value
    Next
    irow = irow + 1  'skip over value row
  End If
Next
```

Or, if you want to clear the dictionary every time you encounter a row containing `#`:

```
For irow = 1 To 10
  If InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 2).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 3).Value, "#") = 0 And InStr(1, objExcel1.Cells(irow, 4).Value, "#") = 0 Then
    For j = 5 To 10
      aDictionary(objExcel1.Cells(irow, j).Value) = objExcel1.Cells(irow + 1, j).Value
    Next
    irow = irow + 1  'skip over value row
  Else
    aDictionary.RemoveAll
  End If
Next
```

The latter would still produce a message box "Empty", though, since there is no "name1" in the rows 8 and 9.

Comment: For removing all the items, it was a big mistake, thank you soo much, I tried your first proposition and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `name1` item to the dictionary, but in the next iteration of the loop you are performing a `.RemoveAll` on the dictionary, deleting that entry. That is why you get an Empty in the messagebox. I think `.RemoveAll` is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: yes, I updated the question, It was a biiiig mistake